# Sitecore ECM 2.1, slow UI

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-ecm

We have just upgraded Sitecore from 6.6 to 7.2, and ECM from 1.3 to 2.1. We are having issues with the Speak UI for ECM being extremely slow. Every operation that seems to fetch data takes several minutes. For example: retrieving the list of recipient lists, where an ajax post request takes minutes to the url http://[domain]/speak/EmailCampaign/TaskPages/AdHockTaskPage?type=Adhoc&id={FD1B449B-C3EA-4820-A10E-E7976A897B8F}&sc_speakcontentlang=nb-NO&ff=1

This is in all our environments (test/production), and we can't get anything from the logs even if we set debug=true on all config settings we can find.

A side note is that we previously used a module to segment the emails (https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_EmailCampaign_Segment.aspx) that is deprecated for our version, so we've tried to clean up items and files for this, without anything getting better.

Has anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with this problem in the future:
This was a bug with the upgrade from 1.3 -> 2.1. Sitecore support filed it as a bug and sent me a dll which partly replaced some rendering logic for a ECM Speak component. So get in touch with Sitecore support and they should be able to help you!

Answer (score 1):

I've had some issues in the past with performance. The general advice is to go through the performance tuning document first:

https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/ecm/200/ecm_tuning_guide_20-usletter.pdf

There are settings described in the document that can fix issues if you have high CPU usage so you should probably check if your CPU is maxing out. The document also describes some of the tools that you can use to measure performance. I found this tool quite useful to give you an idea of what's going on -

/sitecore/admin/dispatchsummary.aspx.

Failing that, you're best off contacting support.

Comment: Thanks! However, I feel like this guide focuses mostly on performance issues while dispatching, and not so much on issues in the UI while setting up the email. Or am I missing something?